# Is there a way to save into a variable a result that is returned within a .then promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, return

I did an API connection to get a query result (arrays of arrays). But Im not able to save the result into another variable and use it with some other function I have created. I get a answer of `Promise {<Pending>}`

Here is the example of the code that works fine when using console.log, and not associated to a variable

```
client.query('SELECT * FROM "INDIGO MONITORING" LIMIT 2;').then(result => console.log(result.rows)).catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Result example: [good Result when testing with `console.log` in `.then`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUek5.png)

Here is my attempt to save the result and getting back `Promise {<pending>}`

```
let results = client.query('SELECT * FROM "INDIGO MONITORING" LIMIT 2;').then(result => {return result}).catch(error => console.log(error));
```

[Result giving Promise Pending](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDQAa.png)

Comment: Results will be a promise. Either continue the “then” chain, or use the await keyword inside an async function

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `await`, but this will (of course) block the entire calling function until the promise is completed. Also, you don't need `then(result => {return result})`, that's the default behavior.

```js
let results = await client.query('SELECT * FROM "INDIGO MONITORING" LIMIT 2;').catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Note: in order for the above line to work, it must be inside a function declared with `async` (e.g. `async function f() {...}`).

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "block the entire calling function"? It's an asynchronous call and as such it will not block the calling function right?

Comment: @Christian no, that's the opposite of what I said. If you use `let x = await func()`, it will block and wait until the promise is completed. It's the entire purpose of `await`, to "wait" for the result.

Comment: The result is awaited yes but a promise is immediately returned so no actual blocking is occurring. The promise will "bubble" up through the call chain right? (All the way to the event loop I guess)

Comment: @Christian no, the promise is not immediately returned. That's the whole purpose of the `await` keyword. After the promise is completed, `result` will contain the value returned through `resolve()` by the promise. Hence, blocking does happen. Test it yourself in your browser or wherever you like: `function f() { return new Promise(r => setTimeout(() => r(123), 3000)) }; console.log(await f());`.

Comment: I thought the point of `async`/`await` was merely syntactic sugaring async code in order to make it more readable and easier to reason about? If I do `await myAsyncFunc()` or for that matter `myAsyncFunc().then(...)` these lines of code will not block but will provide an execution point for the runtime to continue from once the promise has been resolved.
I now realize we have slightly different views on "blocking". Sure, any code after the `await`-ing code won't be executed after the promise has resolved but the program as such will not be blocked.
https://jsfiddle.net/p3uh2fra/1/

Comment: @Christian oh yes, of course. It's not the entire event loop that is blocked, I didn't mean that.

Answer (score 0):

I would write it in another way.

```
 Try{

 Const foo = async () => {
  Let data = await axios.get(<URL>)
  }catch(err){
   Console.log(err)

  }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [`async-await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

```
const getResults = async() => {
  try {
    const results = await client.query('SELECT * FROM "INDIGO MONITORING" LIMIT 2;');
    return results;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return null;
  }
}
```

Below I have simulated a sample `Promise` and ways of handling and processing the response. In both the approaches the promise will be resolved after `500ms`.

- Using `.then` and `.catch`

```js
const examplePromise = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve("Success");
    }, 500)
  })
}

examplePromise().then((res) => {
  console.log(res);
}).catch(err => {
  console.log(err)
});
```

- Using `async` and `await`. In case of `async-await` the errors will be handled/caught using `try/catch`.

```js
const examplePromise = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve("Success");
    }, 500)
  })
}

const asynAwaitEx = async() => {
  try {
    const res = await examplePromise();
    console.log(res);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

asynAwaitEx();
```